# MemoryLeak Valgrind

Tags: linux

```
I am using valgrind for the first time in linux
```

I get the following message  when I run my executable .

```
      ==31440==
      ==31440== FILE DESCRIPTORS: 3 open at exit.
      ==31440== Open file descriptor 2: /dev/pts/9
      ==31440==    <inherited from parent>
      ==31440==
      ==31440== Open file descriptor 1: /dev/pts/9
      ==31440==    <inherited from parent>
      ==31440==
      ==31440== Open file descriptor 0: /dev/pts/9
      ==31440==    <inherited from parent>
      ==31440==
      ==31440==
      ==31440== HEAP SUMMARY:
      ==31440==     in use at exit: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
      ==31440==   total heap usage: 40 allocs, 39 frees, 91,192 bytes allocated
      ==31440==
      ==31440== 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of     1
      ==31440==    at 0x4C277AB: malloc (in    
     /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
    ==31440==    by 0x4EC3AAF: _GLOBAL__sub_I_eh_alloc.cc (eh_alloc.cc:117)
    ==31440==    by 0x400E859: call_init.part.0 (in /lib64/ld-2.18.so)
     ==31440==    by 0x400E942: _dl_init (in /lib64/ld-2.18.so)
     ==31440==    by 0x40011C9: ??? (in /lib64/ld-2.18.so)
     ==31440==
     ==31440== LEAK SUMMARY:
     ==31440==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
     ==31440==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
      ==31440==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
      ==31440==    still reachable: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
      ==31440==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
      ==31440==
      ==31440== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
       ==31440== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

Does this mean that I have a memory leak ? How do I know if there is a memory leak . 
Can anyone of you suggest me links on how to use valgrind and interpret the errors. Thanks in advance .

Comment: That looks like far too many tests of relationships that should already be know.  The list should be assumed to be either empty or correctly sorted before you start.  If you need to special case the first node, do that before the loop, not inside it.  I always use a pointer to pointer in order to avoid special casing the head and by doing so avoid special casing the first node.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decoding output from valgrind](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31248805/decoding-output-from-valgrind)

Answer (score 1):

First, if you have the leak for example in C it means you do a malloc but you don't free it. use `man malloc` and  `man free` for further informations.

I can give you a tip when you launch `Valgrind` you can use the argument `--leak-check=full` and it will show you which malloc you didn't free.

For example:

```
$>valgrind --leak-check=full ./foo.
```

Answer (score 0):

If your program has memory leak, it will specify in the LEAK SUMMARY how many lines has memory leak.

```
 definitely lost: x bytes in 0 blocks
 indirectly lost: y bytes in 0 blocks
```

You can run a quick test by creating a "class obj = new class()" without deleting the obj, you will definitely create a memory leak in your project.